# Изменить цвет кнопки при нажатии в Qt Designer

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer, qss

Как в `StyleSheet` кнопки задать изменение `background-color` при нажатии?

Одна из провалившихся попыток.

[image: Таблица стилей]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
QPushButton {
    border-radius:  10px;
    background-color:  rgb(37, 37, 37);
    color:  rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size:  33px;
}

QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color:  rgb(118, 118, 118);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]